# twilio SMS not received in mobile trial account

Tags: php

I have created trial account on twilio and used test API credentials for sending the SMS, after sending the SMS it shows me SID in success but no message received by the phone number which i have added in 'TO' field.

Comment: Have you added that phone number to the trusted numbers? For the trial I remember that is required.

Answer (score 0):

You must use live credentials to [send messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages):

```
<?php

// this line loads the library 
require('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); 

// you must use your live credentials!!!! 
$account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; 
$auth_token = '[AuthToken]'; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token); 

$client->account->messages->create(array( 
    'To' => "+15558675309", 
    'From' => "+15017250604", 
    'Body' => "Hey, hope this works!", 
    'MediaUrl' => "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1075/1404618563_3ed9a44a3a.jpg",  
));
```

It is explained here - https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials - test credentials do not connect to real phone numbers.